# Generic Type Return and Argument order in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generic-programming, generic-method

I want to create a generic method like below :

```
Task<Response> PerformSomeAction<Request, Response>(
                Request request, string token) 
                where Response : ResponseModel
                where Request : RequestModel;
```

is there any order that we need to maintain while declaring .

can we write like below also?

```
Task<Response> PerformSomeAction<Response, Request>(
                    Request request, string token) 
                    where Response : ResponseModel
                    where Request : RequestModel;
```

is both are same?

Comment: Did you try? What's the perceived benefit?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini does not look like duplicate you suggest is related... Clearly OP knows that both variants are ok (and can even co-exist in the same class) - I believe they are asking for coding style recommendations...

Comment: I am not sure why you would like to intentionally make the code confusing? to me, the natural order is: request, response. I would keep the same order after `where` to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

There is no order needed on declaring generic parameters, however write them the way they seem logical, your first examples (to me seems more logical).

### Original

*I was heading around the garden path of this one, and totally misread the question*

Your calling code cannot switch the generic parameters because you have constraints on the method. in this case the only option you have is to make different overloads of the same method.

That's to say, the first generic parameter, is expecting a type of `RequestModel` as you have denoted in your constraints, you can't send it a ResponseModel. E.g

```
PerformSomeAction<SomeResponse,SomeRequest>()
```

You can (however) overload signatures and generic parameters though

**Exmaple**

```
public class SwitchAroo
{
    Task<Response> PerformSomeAction<Request, Response>(
                    Request request, string token) 
                    where Response : ResponseModel
                    where Request : RequestModel { ... }
    
    Task<Response> PerformSomeAction<Response, Request>(
                        Request request, string token) 
                        where Response : ResponseModel
                        where Request : RequestModel { ... }
}
```

Also just for fun: the compiler will let you overload like this (in general), as the signature is fundamentally different:

```
static Task<U> PerformSomeAction<T, U>(
   T request, string token)  { ... }

static Task<U> PerformSomeAction<U, T>(
   T request, string token)  { ... }
```

But not this, as the signature is essentially the same (if you could it would raise all sorts of strange overload resolution issues):

```
static Task<U> PerformSomeAction<T, U>(
   T request, string token)  { ... }

static Task<U1> PerformSomeAction<T1, U1>(
   T1 request, string token)  { ... }
```

Comment: Much cleaner now - thanks. (I still don't think OP is actually looking for that type of information based on the question).